# How to protect your phone number online?

Tags: php, javascript, security, mobile, spam-prevention

I have been trying to learn the best ways to protect my "contact us" pages from spam-bots and came across this useful resource for protecting my email, after reading it I decided that a contact form would be the easiest and most effective way to protect my email.

http://perishablepress.com/best-method-for-email-obfuscation/

However what if I would like to offer the same protection for a telephone number? Users will not want to fill out a form and wait for the number to come in especially if they are on a  mobile phone.

Implementing a  reverse string would prevent mobile users from calling directly from their device..right?

So my question to you would be:

What is the best way to protect my number against robo calls and scrapers but still maintain "call from device" functionality?

or am I over thinking altogether and should not be worried about this?

****edit****
Based on the answers here and googling I have come to an idea

Here is a fiddle based on my thinking...do you think something like that could work?

http://jsfiddle.net/CampbeII/kwBFz/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // I am not sure how to write this part of the code so i'll be figurative.
    if(browser == mobile_phone){
        //This would wrap the image in a dialable link only if the browser is mobile
        $('#phone_number').wrapInner('<a href="tel:1-800-123-4567"></a>');
    }else{
        //display the image
});
```

Comment: I don't see how it's any different from emails, so I'd still be "worried" about this. I just don't know how much phone numbers are attacked, compared to emails

Comment: I really don't see this as a problem. Modern email clients do a good job of filtering spam, and I rarely, if ever, get calls from solicitors on our company's 800 number.

Comment: I feel as though a program could search for 10 digit numbers in the HTML (similar to emails), add them to a database and use another program to iterate through sending computer generated SMS messages/robocalling to all numbers whether they accept them or not?

Comment: That solution is interesting, but not good for neither email nor phone number. Do a simple copy/paste of the email / number, and see that it will paste it in the wrong direction. Sure the solution is fancy, but not the right thing if you want to do it right. Why not use the classic approach: images?

Comment: Uh, the string `<a href="tel:1-800-123-4567"` is just the thing a simple-minded spambot would scan for - regardless whether occuring in- or outside a script. At least, use something like `$("<a>", {href:"18001234567"})` instead.

Comment: ah okay! thanks for the tip! @em0 said he didn't think the bots executed JS so I figured something like that would help. But doesn't the tel: have to be there to have "call from device" on IOS?
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html

Answer (score 2):

The only way to really do this is to keep your phone number off of the Internet. Meaning you have to call every website that has it listed (or email them) and ask them to remove you from their public listing. Periodically do searches [for the number] online. You can try to obfuscate the phone number with an image, but it exists in other places like domain registries and online yellow pages (if you've paid for a listing). Companies in far off lands with cheap labor pay real people to actually write down phone numbers in lists for calling, then they sell these lists as targeted lists.

In my experience, most [robocallers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocall) will typically use a purchased list from a reputable source because they don't want to waste their resources on calling non-potential clients. Unless it's of course a blanket solicitation, at which point they would use a [war dialer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_dialer).

Comment: If you do searches for it, [insert random search engine] will know your number as well (and won't call it, but use it for ads etc)

Answer (score 0):

What about inserting fake digits using invisible CSS class:

```
<span class="visible">1</span><span class="invisible">9</span><span class="visible">2</span>...
```

So, the visible number is "12...

Comment: Looks much like that cannot be called from the phone either…

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot that numbers can be called on mobile devices. Then use JS for printing the number, spam bots will not execute any JS.

Comment: Evil tip: put 100 invisible fake numbers on the page, which points to extremly high cost services.